# Getting Single Mail via garethp/php-ews

Tags: php, php-ews

Code:

```
$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword($server, $username, $password);
$folder1 = $api->getFolderByDisplayName('PubFolder', DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::PUBLICFOLDERSROOT);
$subFolder1 = $api->getFolderByDisplayName($data['mailfolder'], $folder1->getFolderId());
$api->setFolderId($subFolder1->getFolderId());

$mail = $api->getMailItems($data['id']);
```

Error: `Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function toXmlObject() on string'`

Description: I'd like to get a single Mail item via the id, however since i need to call it from a different page and load the content via JS i am unable to send the MailID object which i can get by using `$singleMail->getItemId()` inside a foreach. So i have to use `$singleMail->getItemId()->getId()` which yields the ID as a string, however when trying to get the mail via ID I get the above error.

So, how should i proceed? Requesting all Mails and looping till i find the ID again is not an option.

Am I using `getMailItems()` wrongly? If so please correct me.

Can i Create the correct ID-Object somehow?

Or is there an alternative way to query a Single Mail via the ID-String? Optionally I would be looking for the manuel building of the Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMailItems` does not take an *email id*, but a *folder id* and it requires it to be an object (`$folderId`) for the first parameter and you're giving a string. If you go and check the [`MailAPI::getMailItems`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/src/MailAPI.php#L79) source, you will understand exactly why you get that error. At [line 91](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/src/MailAPI.php#L91) we see:

```
'FolderId' => $folderId->toXmlObject()
```

there your code tries to call a member function from a string. I searched a bit and I think you can filter the mails by id with `getMailItems` by using the optional parameter `$options`.

First, try to set the `ItemId` to have the string value of mail id like this:

```
$mail = $api->getMailItems($subFolder1->getFolderId(), [
    'ItemIds' => [
        'ItemId' => $data['id'] // Or (new API\Type\ItemIdType($data['id']))
    ]
]);
```

If that won't work, then try to search again for the mail by using this code:

```
$mail = $api->getItem(new API\Type\ItemIdType($data['id']));
```

I don't have an EWS to test this, but I think that's the way you're going to solve the problem.

Comment: @Shaeldon did you try change the `$data['id']` to `new API\Type\ItemIdType($data['id'])` for the first method? Are you sure the second method does not return a single item also? `$mail = $api->getItem(new API\Type\ItemIdType($data['id']));`

Comment: To your comment: yes i tried both. I experimented with your answer a bit and changed it to: $newId = new API\Type\ItemIdType($data['id']);
$mail = $api->getItem($newId); however i recieve 'Cannot use object of type garethp\ews\API\Type\MessageType as array'

Comment: The `ItemIdType` has a `toArray()` method. Try to use that one like this `$mail = $api->getItem($newId->toArray());`

Comment: forget it, i am an idiot. your code works fine, i had some other debug shit there that was before the die();

Comment: thanks for the help, i'll award the bounty in ~18 hours when its possible

Comment: You're welcome. EWS has a bit of a strange way that manages `Items` and `IDs`, but if you get used to it, you'll be able to resolve that kind of issues more easily. I'm glad that you got this solved.